# How to change the default value of propertyPanePageTitle in Property pane?

Tags: typescript

I working on my first spfx web part using TypeScript, now i want to change the default value of propertyPanePageTitle, how can I do that?
Thank you. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This value comes from your web part manifest.json file located in the root folder of your web part. It is taken from the `title` field located in your group entry within the `preconfiguredEntries` array. Updating this value (stop any running gulp serve and run again) should reflect the change.

Comment: Thank you brother, i did the change it worked fine.